# SQL Server 2008 R2 Spatial Queries

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, spatial

I am very new to the spatial realm of SQL Server and need some help.  I have a waypoint organizing app and I am trying to generate some queries that follow along the premise of finding waypoints that are part of geographic polygons like lakes, rivers, etc.  I have preloaded my tables with data I have downloaded.  I used shape2sql.exe to load shapefiles into the appropriate db tables.

Tables are as follows:
Water table - id, name, geog(geography data type)
State table - id, state_name, state_abbr, geog(geography data type)
County table - id, name, state_name, geog(geography data type)
Waypoint table - id, name, lat, lon, waterid

How do I write queries against these tables to return things like:
- all waypoints in 'michigan'
- all waypoints on 'bass lake' in 'montcalm' county in 'michigan' (there  are multiple bass lakes in michigan and the country hence the county/state part)
- auto assign the water id column of the waypoint table by "processing" a group of waypoints and finding what lake they actually belong to
- etc.

Thanks!

Learned so far:
    select geog.ToString() as Points, geog.STArea() as Area, geog.STLength() as Length
    from water
    where name like '%bass lake%' and STATE = 'mi'

will return the record for Bass Lake and the polygon with the actual coordinates for the lake.
POLYGON ((-87.670498549804691 46.304831340698243, -87.670543549804691 46.307117340698241, -87.676573549804687 46.313480340698241, -87.68120854980468 46.314821340698245, -87.685168549804686 46.315703340698242, -87.6877605498047 46.313390340698241, -87.685051549804683 46.308827340698244, -87.682360549804685 46.305650340698243, -87.677734549804683 46.304768340698246, -87.674440549804686 46.304336340698242, -87.670498549804691 46.304831340698243)) 1022083.96662664    4027.52433709888

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok - learning as I go so here are some answers to my own questions for anyone what would like to know.

Here is one query for finding various waypoints with conditions in the where clause:
    SELECT * FROM WaypointTable wp
    JOIN WaterTable w
    ON wp.geogcolumn.STIntersects(w.geogcolumn) = 1
    WHERE w.name LIKE '%bass lake%'
    AND w.state = 'mi';

Here is a query for assigning water id's to waypoints based on where they 'fit':
    UPDATE WaypointTable wp
    SET WaterID = (
      SELECT ID
      FROM WaterTable
      WHERE geogcolumns.STIntersects(wp.geogcolumn) = 1
    );

Both of these queries work extremely well and fast!  Love it!

Answer (score 0):

Shooting from the hip, here, but maybe like this:

```
UPDATE  waypoints
SET waypoints.WaterId = water.Id
FROM    dbo.Waypoints AS waypoints LEFT JOIN
    dbo.Water AS water ON geography::Point(waypoints.Lat, waypoints.Lon, 4326).STIntersects(water.geog)
```

Should set the waterId on the wapoints table to one of the matching water ids, from the water table.

This should get you all the waypoints on BASS LAKE

```
SELECT  waypoints.*
FROM    dbo.Waypoints as waypoints INNER JOIN
    dbo.Water AS water ON geography::Point(waypoints.Lat, waypoints.Lon, 4326).STIntersects(water.geog) = 1
WHERE   water.Name = 'BASS_LAKE' -- OR WHATEVER
```

Comment: Does the geography::point need longitude then latitude and the srid?  getting some kind of error about longitude needing to be between -90 and 90 ......